# What does ～とか mean when it doesn't indicate an example?

Tags: grammar

> 事故【じこ】があった**とか**で電車【でんしゃ】が止まり【とまり】……

Here とか does not seem to indicate an 'example'.
Do I understand it correctly?
What does this form of `とか` represent?

Comment: It's more like vague "kinda" or "something like ～", rather than explicit "etc" or "such as". Basically it's something used to avoid making a definitive statement, and it appears almost anywhere... An awful but grammatical example would be 「事故とかがあったとかで電車とかが止まるとかで…」

Comment: @IUnknown Most/all of the Japanese sentences you quote in your questions seem to be originally written in kanji + kana. Why do you (re)write them in hiragana only?

Comment: Could you tell us where the quotes in your questions come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right. This 「とか」 does not indicate an example. The 「とか」 in 「事故{じこ}があったとかで電車｛でんしゃ}が停まり{とまり}・・・」 is

> 《格助詞「と」＋副助詞「か」》はっきりしない事柄を指示する意を表す。「家族が病気だ―で困っているらしい」
>   [case marker *to* + adverbial particle *ka*] Indicates that something is unclear or undetermined.

from meaning #1 in [goo辞書「とか」](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/157481/m0u/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8B/). Your sentence could be rewritten as:

> 事故があった（ということ）らしく電車が停まり・・・
>   事故があったそうで電車が停まり・・・

Examples:

> この辺りは昔からリンゴで有名だとか。接続:「普通形」+とか ([日本語能力試験N2・文法](http://quizlet.com/15501318/n2-flash-cards/)) (≒ 有名だとのこと。/有名だそうです。/有名だという話です。/有名だと聞きましたが。)
>   [ルーズソックスも流行っているのだとか！](http://matome.naver.jp/odai/2141234580212260601/2141273583831824003)(≒ はやっているとのこと。/はやっているそうです。/はやっているという話です。)

---

The 「とか」 in 「アツアツおでんとかそういうのはやらないので」 indicates an example and is meaning #2 in [goo辞書「とか」](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/157481/m0u/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8B/):

> 《並立助詞「と」＋副助詞「か」 》 ２ 断定を避け、あいまいにするために語の後に付ける。「学校―から帰る」
>   [parallel marker *to* + adverbial particle *ka*] Connects to the right of words to make them less conclusive and introduce ambiguity.

Comment: goo辞書の#1と#2-2は、説明だけ見ても違いがピンと来ないのですが、要するに「曖昧な伝聞」と「曖昧な例示」の違い、みたいな理解でいいのでしょうか。

Comment: あ、そんな気がしますね。。。それから品詞と接続が違いますね。goo辞書に『伝聞』って書いてないけど、「伝聞ちゃうの～？」ってちょっと思いました

Comment: The definitions also did not do much for me, but the fact it lists the second 「と」 as 並立助詞 is pretty educational.

Comment: 一個目の「と」って、格助詞のなかでも、quotative だと思うね・・(「引用の格助詞」?)